# Impresion condicional de DataItemTemplate en un Grid

Tags: c#, .net, asp, gridview

Recibo un valor estado que puede ser 20 o 90.
Dependiendo del estado, decido si mostrar el html o no.

Hasta ahora lo estaba haciendo con `#Eval('Estado')` y no me estaba dando ningún problema. Los quebraderos de cabeza han llegado cuando me he encontrado con la paginación... la segunda página la muestra vacía!

Por descarte (comentandolo) el problema esta en el eval.

Por lo tanto, existe alguna alternativa para llamar a ese dato y condicionar la impresión del HTML?

El objetivo de esto es que necesito mostrar los botones solo en caso de que se cumpla la condicion antes descrita.

Os coloco una versión reducida del grid, sin los montones de columnas que tiene.

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="ClientesGridView"
    DataSourceID="sqlClientes"
    ClientInstanceName="ClientesGridView"
    EnableRowsCache="False"
    runat="server"
    KeyFieldName="CodigoCliente"
    OnAutoFilterCellEditorInitialize="grid_AutoFilterCellEditorInitialize"
    OnHtmlDataCellPrepared="grid_HtmlDataCellPrepared">
    <ClientSideEvents
        RowClick="function(s, e) {  SMCVisitasClientes_SeeCliente(e); }"
    }"  />
    <Settings ShowGroupPanel="true" ShowFilterRow="true" />
    <SettingsPager PageSize="20"></SettingsPager>
    <SettingsBehavior ConfirmDelete="true" />
    <Styles>
    <AlternatingRow Enabled="true" />
    </Styles>
    <Columns>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn VisibleIndex="99">
            <DataItemTemplate>
                <%#Eval("Estado").ToString()!="90" ?
                "<input type=\"button\" title=\"Nuevo contacto\" style=\"background: url(../../Style%20Library/Images/add_user_32x32.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; border: none; cursor: pointer;\" width=\"40\" height=\"40\" id=\"AddContacto\"/>"+
                "<input type=\"button\" title=\"Nueva visita\" style=\"background: url(../../Style%20Library/Images/Add_Visit.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; border: none; cursor: pointer;\" width=\"40\" height=\"40\" id=\"AddVisit\"/>"
                :"" %>
            </DataItemTemplate>
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
    </Columns>
</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

Comment: Disculpa pero, ¿cual es el problema exactamente?

Comment: Pues que cuando uso la condicion en codigo servidor con el eval, la paginacion del grid no funciona.No tengo ni idea de cual sera la relacion entre ellos. pero casca.

Comment: Verificaste que la consulta te trae mas de 20 resultados?

Comment: Si, me trae unas 1700 paginas... Sin tener esa columna puedo paginar perfectamente. Cuando coloco esa columna me pega cascotazo...

Comment: podras poner el codigo del lado del servidor? podrias usar el evento grid_HtmlDataCellPrepared que definiste para cambiar el valor por el html que necesitas.

Comment: Gracias @WFgo, voy a probar y te digo.

Comment: El "e.DataColumn.Name" me recorre todas las columnas del grid menos esa! :( Es un proyecto recogido, me imagino que definira en algun lado alguna propiedad... pero no encuentro donde puede ser